# GUI Built with Pynsist and PyQt: Import Error 'sip'

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pynsist

I have built a GUI using `PyQt5` and wanted to distribute it to other computers without `Python` installed by packageing it with `pynsist`. Unfortunately, when launching the shortcuts produced by the installer, the GUI does not open as expected and `Python` keeps crashing (even if `Python` is instlalled).

The console shows the following error upon crashing:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sip'.
```

This is due to `from PyQt5.QtCore import *`.

Unfortunately, when launching the `.launch.py` script on a computer with `Python` installed, everything works fine. I suppose this is because it then targets the installed version instead of the version included in the build of the GUI.
However, the shortcuts do not work, no matter if `Python` is installed, giving me the above error.

Any ideas how to fix this problem and make the shortcuts work on computers that do not have `Python` installed?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I first encountered this problem I simply added `sip.pyd` to my project-folder. You can find it under:

```
x:/path-to-python/Lib/site-packages/sip.pyd
```

but what realy solved my problem was [using pyinstaller](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyInstaller/).
It automatically detects most dependencies and most of the time runs without complicated configurations.

```
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller main.py 
# done
```

Comment: Pyinstaller would be nice. However, I'm more or less bound to `pynsist`, since my end-users won't have `Python` installed. Thus, I need to incorporate a functioning `Python` instance.

I tried to copy the `sip.pyd` file into the project folder in different places, but it still tells me that `sip` is missing. Can you please specify where I should paste it?

Comment: @alex_555: Pyinstaller will provide a full python-instance, with all required modules (or most). No Python-installation is needed on the running maschine. Regarding the sip-module: you can place it whereever you like, simply add the path to it (**before first depending import!**) with `sys.path.append( os.path.realpath( 'relative/path' ) )`

Comment: I tried to Pyinstaller and it works so much better! Although there are a few things left, this question is answered! Thank you!

Comment: What to do on a mac?

Answer (score 2):

Sip is a [separate package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SIP) which PyQt5 requires. You can include it with your application by listing it in `pypi_wheels=`, as in the [PyQt5 example](https://github.com/takluyver/pynsist/blob/master/examples/pyqt5/installer.cfg):

```
[Include]
packages=listapp
pypi_wheels= PyQt5==5.6
    sip==4.18
```

If you're using the latest version of PyQt5 (5.10.1), then the latest version of sip (4.19.8) should work with it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably try that and see if it works later, but for now I'm well served with Pyinstaller. Just as a side note: as great as Pyinstaller is, the only thing I really miss is the opportunity to automatically create shortcuts compared to pynsist without having to build a workaround for that.

Comment: Ironically, Pyinstaller does not actually make installers (at least not normally; maybe it has some mode for that). Pynsist does, which is why it gives you shortcuts.

Comment: This is actually the reason why I preferred pynsist in the first place, since most end-users are accustomed to using an installer and working with the shortcuts. However, Pyinstaller created fewer problems and worked quite well so that I distributed the beta version of my GUI with it. But I'll probably come back later for trying to make pynsist also work.